# COM & CoGetClassObject()

Tags: c++, com

I have a little problem with `CoGetClassObject()`.

I have an application which must use some DLLs of a specific version,
but they are also present in the system, in a more recent version.

So I start hooking the `CoCreateInstance()` and `loadLibrary()`, which I guess are good.
The problem is that the DLLs in the two versions are loaded.

So I think that `CoGetClassObject()` is the problem/solution because it provides a pointer to an interface  of an object associated with a CLSID containing a DLL that the application must use in an older version.

But I don't know what this function "does", so how can I "override" this function ?

thanks.

PS : I'm new in the COM programming.

Answer (score 6):

CoGetClassObject() simply does half the job that CoCreateInstance() does.  It returns a class factory.  CoCreateInstance() then call IClassFactory::CreateInstance() and releases the IClassFactory.  You would only use it if you have a need to create many objects of a certain coclass and want to optimize that.  It avoids the cost of creating and releasing the factory over and over again.

You are possibly overlooking a far simpler solution to this problem.  You can simply copy the new version of the COM server DLL into the same directory as the client EXE.  And create a zero byte file with the name "app.exe.local" where "app" is the name of the EXE.  That's enough to force that copied DLL to be loaded instead of the one that the registry points to.  The MSDN Library article about DLL redirection [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375142%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But add the .local file didn't change anything.

So I called from CoGetClassObjectHooked() CoCreateInstance(which must be hooked by my CoCreateInstanceHooked) and CreateInstance(NULL,riid,ppv) but this last return an E_NOINTERFACE.

Comment: The point of the tip was to *not* do any hooking at all.  Just to let it load the copied DLL automatically.  Boring but effective.

Comment: Yes, I did not hooking, I just add the .local file. But the two versions were loaded.

Comment: Let's focus on the bigger mystery.  How is it even possible?  COM servers have to be registered to be usable.  Two different versions with the same registry keys cannot co-exist, the last one registered will overwrite the registration of the first one.  Which means that the first one can never be found.  What's going on in your program?

Comment: Well maybe it's because the dlls I want in a minor version are "protected" ?

Answer (score 1):

The very simple explanation is `CoGetClassObject()` opens `HKCR\CLSID\{ClassId}` and looks at `InProcServer32` or `LocalServer32` depending on what `CLSCTX_*` value is passed - that is the COM server path.

Once it find a COM server file path is loads (`LoadLibraryEx()` with `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` flag in case of in-proc or `CreateProcess()` in case of out-proc) the COM server. Then it locates and calls `DllGetClassObject()` for in-proc servers or waits until a class factory is registered for out-proc servers.

This of course ignores stuff like DCOM etc. You can get a better idea of how it traverses the registry using Process Monitor utility.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a specific COM DLL regardless of whether there is a newer version installed, and regardless of where the older DLL is located, then simply ignore `CoCreateInstance()` and `CoGetClassObject()` altogether.  Load the older DLL yourself via `LoadLibrary()`, then call its exported `DllGetClassObject()` function directly to get the DLL's `IClassFactory` interface, then call `IClassFactory::CreateInstance()` as needed.  This is all `CoCreateInstance()` and `CoGetClassObject()` do internally anyway, but this bypasses the Registry lookups they perform to determine the DLL path to load.

Comment: This also bypasses marshalling and threading models which is not always good.

Comment: I Think it's what I already do.
In the CoCreateInstanceHook()&CoGetClassObjectHook(), I just do that :
`module = LoadLibraryWReal(lib);
dllGetClassObject = (FUNC) GetProcAddress(module,"DllGetClassObject");
hr = dllGetClassObject(rclsid, IID_IClassFactory, &pClassFactory);
hr = pClassFactory->CreateInstance(NULL,riid,ppv);`

It seems working in the CoCreateInstane() but in the CoGetClassObject() I got an E_NOINTERFACE